# ASP.NET Core 3.1 url forwarding

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm running an ASP.NET Core 3.1 webapp. Url's have this format:

https://www.example.com/nl/controller/action/id

'nl' is a language parameter. Is there any way around to forward traffic that uses another language value than 'nl'?

So when someone is visiting 'https://www.example.com/en/controller/action/id' it should be forwarded to 'https://www.example.com/nl/controller/action/id'.

Can this be set up via Startup.cs?

Comment: On what condition do you want to redirect the user? Always or does it depends on certain conditions?

Comment: There is no condition... All url's with the wrong language parameters should be redirected.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to redirect from the route config. You could add a language wildcard route and use a `return RedirectToAction()` in the controller to redirect the users to the correct URL. Or maybe add a global 404 route and use a regex to check for the invalid language URL and replace and redirect the user to the correct URL.